# Acumatica return to function with PXLongOperation

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating an integration for Acumatica that loads data from another application to synchronize inventory items. It uses an API call to get a list (of up to 5000 items) and then I'm using `PXLongOperation` to insert or update these items. I can't run it without this method as the large batches (aka inserting 5000 stock items) will timeout and crash.

The processing form is a custom table/form that retrieves this information then parses the JSON list of items and calls a custom function on the InventoryItemMaint graph. All that works perfectly, but it never returns to the calling function. I'd love to be able to write information to record to record that it was a success or failure. I've tried `PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion` but that doesn't seem to change anything. I'm sure I'm not using the asynchronous nature of this correctly but am wondering if there is a reasonable work around.

```cs
            // This is the lsit of items from SI
            List<TEKDTools.TEKdtoolModels.Product> theItems;

            if (Guid.TryParse(Convert.ToString(theRow.DtoolsID), out theCatID))
            {
              
                // Get the list of items from dtools.
                theItems = TEKDTools.TEKdtoolsCommon.ReadOneCatalog(theCatID);
              
                  // Start the long operation              
                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate () {
                  // Create the graph to make a new Stock Item
                  InventoryItemMaint itemMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
                  
                  var itemMaintExt = itemMaint.GetExtension<InventoryItemMaintTEKExt>();
              
                  foreach (TEKDTools.TEKdtoolModels.Product theItem in theItems)
                  {
                      itemMaint.Clear();
                      itemMaintExt.CreateUpdateDToolsItem(theItem, true);
                      PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(itemMaint.UID);
                    }
                 }    
                );
                                              
            }

            stopWatch.Stop(); // Just using this to figure out how long things were taking.
            // For fun I tried the Wait Completion here too
            PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(this.UID);
            theRow = MasterView.Current;

            // Tried some random static values to see if it was writing
            theRow.RowsCreated = 10;
            theRow.RowsUpdated = 11;

    
            theRow.Data2 = "Elasped Milliseconds: " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            theRow.RunStart = startTime;
            theRow.RunEnd = DateTime.Now;
            
            // This never gets the record udpated.
            Caches[typeof(TCDtoolsBatch)].Update(theRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the PXLongOperation.SetCustomInfo method. Usually this is used to update the UI thread after the long operation has been finished. In this "class" you can subscribe to events which you can use to update rows. The definition of the class is as follows:

```
public class UpdateUICustomInfo : IPXCustomInfo
{
    public void Complete(PXLongRunStatus status, PXGraph graph)
    {
        // Set Code Here
    }
}
```

The wait completion method you are using, generally is used to wait for another long operation to finish by passing the key of that long operation.